# run python code using html5

Tags: python, html, user-interface, web2py

Basically I want to create a sexy GUI using HTML5 then call code that I wrote in python. I have just discovered some tutorials about web2py, however I am getting the videos now from youtube so I can only watch when I get home. (Life of a student with no internet at home).

So basically I have written a python script, now I want to use a webpage to interact with that script instead of terminal as I have been doing. So I have a webpage provide me the GUI to my python app.

Hope this makes more sense.

Any help and direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have never used web2py but Flask and Bottle are 2 frameworks that are pretty lightweight and easy to learn.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/webservers.html) page in the docs?

Comment: Having a look now. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to flip that around, you want to run server-side python code that renders your sexy HTML5 GUI. There are many Python frameworks that are suitable to this, including [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/), [django](http://www.djangoproject.com), and my personal favorite [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Any of these frameworks will let your python code run, then render the HTML with python variables/functions available by using a templating engine (for example Flask uses [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) template). Tutorials are readily available for all of these python libraries, but if you want to take a look at Flask, I can recommend [Miguel Grinberg's excellent tutorial series.](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes more sense now! Much appreciated.

Comment: @binaryatrocity, Why flask?